# Asp.net MVC Firefox shows hyperlink location in parentheses, why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, hyperlink

http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/1331/19748435.png

Looking at that image is the menu bar on my webpage.  So far simple but why would firefox show the link in the parentheses while IE doesn't?  I disabled all of my addons and it still does it.  I looked at the source in firebug and it shows exactly what's in the HTML:

```
<div id="menu" >
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Documentation</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Developer Tools</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Database</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Management</a></li>
            </ul>  
        </div>
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Need to see all of your view code and the controller code.

Comment: For this View, and the Controller for this view.

Comment: Nevermind, it was a CSS file that should not have been there.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had removed one of the script files which seemed to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I was missing the media attribute in my link to css elements. I am using blueprint css. Guess it's mandatory to put

```
media="screen, projection"
media="print"
```

in the links to the css and I somehow missed to copy those attributes over.

Answer (score 1):

Look into your .css file (especially print.css if you are using it) and remove a line that looks like this:

a:link:after, a:visited:after {content:" (" attr(href) ")";font-size:90%;}

I wasn't aware of css like this until I had the same issue as the person above. Hope it'll save somebody some time in the future - it drove me bananas for an hour!!

Comment: Sorry - just to clarify - this is only applicable if you do not specify the media attribute for the .css file. (if it's not something you want on printing)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the href="" with href="#"

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "" with  "\0"